# Counting passengers on a moving object in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to develop a system that will count passengers on a moving object(kiddies train) only. The current model I have is based on deep learning but it also counts the people I do not need. I want the model to count only passengers and exclude train driver and surrounding people. I am attaching an image. The count and trip information needs to be exported to the database and CSV file. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: show some code . maybe you can diversify people who are still and people who are on the move, or people who are close and people who are far away, people who are moving in one direction rather than another. Or exclude those with a certain color uniform.

Comment: Thanks Mario, should I  add the code here, as it is a long comment. I also have a pic showing what I want to improve on.  Regards Samantha

Comment: Sure ,you can. Share with us